# Creating worksheets from templates

Tags: excel, collections, foreach, compiler-errors, vba

We have around 100 departments in our organization that require a budget.

I have a master Budget Workbook template that has 11 worksheets.

- 1<sup>st</sup> worksheet is **Data** with various data
- 2<sup>nd</sup>-11<sup>th</sup> worksheets are the 10 **major categories** that each department will use in creating their annual budget

I need to create a workbook for each department that has the 10 worksheets.

On the **Data** worksheet, `Column C` has all the **Department Numbers** that will have a budget, and `Column U` has the list of the names of the worksheets that are the 10 major expense categories (**Budget Categories**).

[image: Departments & Worksheet Names]

I need to create a copy of each worksheet for each department, and name the worksheet using the account number, and the existing worksheet name.

For example:

```
111100-Category-A
111100-Category-B
111100-Category-C
111100-Category-D
111100-Category-E
111100-Category-F
111100-Category-G
111100-Category-H
111100-Category-I
111100-Category-J
```

I was trying to loop through each of the account numbers and worksheet names with the code below.

Right now, I'm getting a

> Compile Error:  For Each may only iterate over a collection object or
>   an array.

#### Here is my code

```
Option Explicit
Sub Add_Sheets()
Dim TabList As String, wsName As Range, Acct As Range, extraSheet As Worksheet
With Sheets("Data")
TabList = .Range("U2:U11")
For Each wsName In TabList
Set extraSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("wsName")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng = .Range(.[c2], .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))

For Each Acct In rng
    extraSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = Acct & "-" & "TabList"
Next
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more errors in your code than just the one mentioned. Here is the solution to the bug you found however:

```
Dim TabList As String, wsName As Range, Acct As Range, extraSheet As Worksheet
```

Here is another issue I spotted:

```
Set extraSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsname.value)
```

Comment: Thanks TTG!  I'm new to VBA (very obvious)  and wasn't sure about the syntax for (wsname.value) Thank you again!

Comment: Good luck on your macro. If you get further along and encounter more problems you can't solve, please post a new question.

Comment: Thank you TTG!  If you have any other suggestions I'm open!